# Cross-platform compatibility of dprintf

Tags: c, linux, posix, conditional-compilation

Linux has this nice function [`dprintf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dprintf):

> The functions `dprintf()` and `vdprintf()` (as found in the glibc2 library) are exact analogues of `fprintf()` and `vfprintf()`, except that they output to a file descriptor fd instead of to a given stream.

however as that same source points out:

> These functions are GNU extensions, not in C or POSIX. Clearly, the names were badly chosen. Many systems (like MacOS) have incompatible functions called `dprintf()`, usually some debugging version of `printf()`, perhaps with a prototype like

```
void dprintf (int level, const char *format, ...);
```

> where the first parameter is a debugging level (and output is to `stderr`). Moreover, `dprintf()` (or `DPRINTF`) is also a popular macro name for a debugging `printf`. So, probably, it is better to avoid this function in programs intended to be portable.

### My question

How can I make a setup that will safely call the `dprintf` that I want, if it exists, or fail to compile with some reasonably sane error message if that function doesn't exist? I guess I'd do something like this:

```
#ifdef SOMETHING
    #define Dprintf dprintf
#else
    #error "no dprintf"
#endif
```

but I don't know what `SOMETHING` should be. I guess I could restrict it to just Linux but could I make it looser?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like `dprintf()` is actually in [POSIX.1-2008](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dprintf.html) (with the semantics you want), so you can do this:

```
#if !defined(__GLIBC__) && _POSIX_C_SOURCE < 200809
#error "dprintf may not exist, or may be wrong"
#endif
```

`__GLIBC__` is defined if you're using a gnu build system.  This is probably as safe as you can be without writing a small test program.

Comment: BTW, it is frequent to see things like `(_POSIX_C_SOURCE - 0) < 200809` so that it's still a valid (false) expression even when the macro is undefined or empty.

Comment: But if something isn't defined, the pre-processor will substitute 0 for it, so `_POSIX_C_SOURCE < 200809` will expand to `0 < 200809` if `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` is not defined or is 0.  For empty macros, you're right.

Answer (score 4):

You could make an autoconf test, if you're using autotools for your buildsystem.

```
AC_LANG([C])
AC_USE_SYSTEM_EXTENSIONS
AC_ARG_WITH([dprintf],
  [AS_HELP_STRING([--with-dprintf],
    [Assume that dprintf prints to a specified file descriptor])],
  [], [with_dprintf=check])
AS_IF([test "x$with_dprintf" = xcheck],
  [AC_RUN_IFELSE(
    [AC_LANG_PROGRAM([[
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <string.h>
        int debug_level;
      ]], [[
        char msg[] = "Hello, world!\n";
        char rcv[sizeof(msg)] = "";
        FILE *f = tmpfile();
        int fd = fileno(f);
        debug_level = fd - 1;
        dprintf(fd, "%s", msg);
        fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
        fread(rcv, 1, sizeof(msg), f);
        return strcmp(msg, rcv);
      ]]
    )], [with_dprintf=yes])])
AS_IF([test "x$with_dprintf" = xyes],
  [AC_DEFINE([HAVE_DPRINTF], [1],
    [dprintf prints to a specified file descriptor])])
```

(Allowing for `--with-dprintf` or `--without-dprintf` when cross-compiling, as `AC_RUN_IFELSE` isn't valid in those cases.)

---

[fdopen](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/fdopen.html) isn't in standard C, but it *is* in POSIX.2 and later.  I don't recall any UNIX-like that doesn't have it -- heck, even Windows has it.

```
int fdprintf(int fd, char *fmt, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    FILE *f = fdopen(fd);
    int rc;

    va_start(ap, &fmt);
    rc = vfprintf(f, fmt, ap);
    fclose(f);
    va_end(ap);
    return rc;
}
```

Of course, if you know which file descriptor you'll be printing to, just keep the `FILE*` pointer around instead.

Comment: I don't have a build system (OK, I'm using make via the make-remaking-make files thing)

Answer (score 2):

An Autoconf test could check whether `dprintf(1, "blablabla")` writes to stdout or stderr, and whether `dprintf(-1, "blablabla")` fails in an interesting way or writes to stderr.

If libc gives you with the wrong `dprintf()`, you could implement it yourself on top of `snprintf()` (or even better `asprintf()`) and `write()`. And then mention your 'dprintf.o' to the linker so it prefers yours to libc's.

If you want a better name, I propose `fdprintf()`.

Comment: +1 (even thought I'm not using autoconf, or any configuration for that matter) -- I'm using dprintf in place of asprintf+write because it's used in an error handler and I don't want to have to worry about the heap working.

Comment: @BCS: You don't need to use the heap, your function can allocate the buffer on the stack (either a fixed size buffer, or with `alloca()`)

Comment: @Hasturkun: Fixed size won't work (I don't have a reasonable upper bound on length) and under some error recovery situations, stack space is very tight.

Comment: Implementing it on top of `snprintf` or `asprintf` is a bad idea, as these require the string to fit in memory and have failure cases. Instead, use `fdopen` and then just use `fprintf`.

Comment: @R: To quote Mr. Simpson: "Duh!".

Comment: @R Given that it returns a pointer I expect fdopen requires a usable heap. As long as that's a valid assumption, good. If not, we are back to my original objection to `asprintf`.